# Can I use Python's Pygal module to visualize data from an SQLalchemy database?

Tags: python, database, charts, sqlalchemy, pygal

How can I convince Pygal to pull data from 2 tables in an SQLAlchemy database?

These are my models:

```
class PlannedPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default='planned')
    category = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default=None)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    planned_amount = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    date_period = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    comments = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}, '{self.category}'\
        , '{self.name}', '{self.planned_amount}'\
        , '{self.date_period}', '{self.comments}')"

class ActualPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default='actual')
    category = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default=None)
    actual_amount_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    actual_amount = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    comments = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ActualPost('{self.title}, '{self.category}'\
        , '{self.actual_amount_name}', '{self.actual_amount}'\
        , '{self.date_posted}', '{self.comments}')"
```

And this is what the route I dreamed up, which I know is wrong because it seems that Pygal can use only lists.

```
@posts.route("/graphing")
def graphing():
    planned = PlannedPost.query
    actual = ActualPost.query
    graph = pygal.Bar()
    graph.title = 'Planned Values vs Actual Values'
    graph.x_labels = planned.title
    graph.add('Planned', [planned.planned_amount])
    graph.add('Actual', [actual.actual_amount])
    graph_data = graph.render_data_uri()
    return render_template('graphing.html', graph_data=graph_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is "yes". One can visualise data from a database using Pygal.

See this question for code example: [Python Pygal chart pulling data from database not matching values to labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50748569/python-pygal-chart-pulling-data-from-database-not-matching-values-to-labels)